# Nesting ES6 Classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, nested, modularity

In a hybrid mobile app that I am currently developing I am incorporating the ability for the app to change its entire front end based on what its user chooses to do.  I am doing this by downloading a "personality module" in the form of an ES6 file similar to the one below.

```js
window.guff = class
{
 static Hello(){alert('Hello from Window.guff');}
 
 static gaff = class
 {
  static Hello(){alert('Bonjour from Window.guff.gaff');}
 } 
 
 static goo = class
 {
  static Hello(){alert('Ciao from Window.guff.goo');}
 }
  
}

guff.Hello();
guff.gaff.Hello();
guff.goo.Hello();
```

Needless to say each personality module will have the same class hierarchy and the same methods (with due care taken in app code to handle slipups in the form of missing methods and/or nested classes).

This works - at least in Chrome.  However, it is not entirely clear to me that this is legal use of ES6.  VSCode keeps flagging up "errors" though I suspect that is down to JSHint being unable to cope with my code.

My question - is such use of ES6 classes legit?  If not, is there a better way of accomplishing what I want to do here?

Comment: Everything on those classes is static. Why aren't they plain objects?

Comment: If you want to use ES6, why not use a module (with named exports)?

Answer (score 1):

> My question - is such use of ES6 classes legit? If not, is there a
> better way of accomplishing what I want to do here?

As @quentin pointed out, plain objects are the way:

```
window.guff = {
    Hello: () => { alert('Hello from Window.guff'); },
    gaff: {
        Hello: () => { alert('Bonjour from Window.guff.gaff'); }
    },
    goo: {
        Hello: () => { alert('Ciao from Window.guff.goo'); }
    },
};
```

If you want to **lock** this object, you might want to take a look at **Object.freeze(window.guff)**